# New iOS App struggling with Facebook Graph api v2.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm new to app development, and I've been building a social iOS app that requires sending Facebook invites to join the app. Yesterday's release of Facebook Graph API 2.0 seems to have much stricter requirements on how to invite those not already part of the game. I'm trying to activate me/invitable_friends but I keep getting the same message:

```
{
 "error": {
"message": "(#15) This method is only accessible to Games.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 15
 }
```

Their documentation mentions needing to be a Canvas app, so I added placeholder URL's as Canvas pages. Not sure if that's sufficient.

Admittedly my app is still in sandbox mode so that could be why, though I get the same message when testing with the Graph API application itself. Is it due to being in sandbox mode, or is there something else I need to do? Do all apps now have to be approved by Facebook to integrate their invites?

Comment: Hey, can you provide me with your app ID and I'll investigate why it might not be working for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the invitable_friends edge, your app needs to be:

- classified as a 'Game' within your app's settings
- have a Canvas presence - which means enabling the Canvas platform within your app's settings.

The error you're seeing above is because your app is not categorized as a game, not because you're in Development Mode.

Comment: WOW thank you so much! I never would have figured that out on my own.

Does it matter that my app doesn't qualify in one of Facebook's 'game' categories and the Canvas doesn't lead anywhere? Will there be some consequence on FB's end at some point?

Comment: No problem! - theres a big note at the top of this doc which explains how this works: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends

Comment: Also, yes it does matter:

1/ your app actually has to be a game. To be classified as a game, and not actually be one is in violation of out policies.

2/ if you enable a canvas presence, it must be a properly supported platform - i.e. your game must be playable in canvas. To have an empty canvas page, or to redirect out of canvas is also against FB's policies.

Comment: Thanks Simon. This is the first thing I've ever coded, so pardon my ignorance. From looking at the subcategories of games within the Facebook API, they seem somewhat limited. For example, Quora connects with Facebook at the moment to add your friends, but with this new policy that would no longer be the case. Is that Facebook's intention?

Comment: Is that Facebook's intention? No. Facebook likes breaking things - I have been with this for about five years, every half a year we need to fix things because FB breaks something. This particular time, they tried to be Apple and they "identified the only use-cases that are needed for most of the apps". Hence the "invitable_friends" and "taggable_friends" concept. But they didn't do it right... I opened an issue on this bug - you can help by subscribing, commenting and reopening - it is the only think we can do at this moment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/

Comment: I already have categorised as Games my app though i am getting same error.Plz help me

Comment: @adamf1983 - no - apps retain access to the subset of a person's friends who've also logged into the app with FB - so when you login to an app they're still able to connect you with your friends who're already using that app.