# Facebook iOS invitable_friends returns empty data

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to send app invites to friends which do not have iOS app installed using Facebook. 
In Facebook documentation it says that `/me/invitable_friends` path is used for it. Problem is that response `data` is always empty without any error. I've granted `user_friends` permission. 
I have created Canvas page but in Settings I've set Canvas URL to http://localhost.com/facebook/. Thing is that this game needs to be iOS only without Canvas. Is it possible to achieve sending app invites without Canvas?

Here is my request:

> ```
> [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/invitable_friends"
>                              parameters:nil
>                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"
>                       completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
>
>                           NSLog(@"Resulr: %@", result);
>                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
>                       }];
> ```

This is the output:

> Result: {
>       data =     (
>       ); } Error: (null)

Comment: See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412709/new-ios-app-struggling-with-facebook-graph-api-v2-0

Comment: Thanks for response but my app category is Games and I've created test Canvas page. Still I'm getting data empty...

Answer (score 0):

Old question but still unresolved ? For me, that answer fixed the issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596530/2452521