# Facebook APP: Empty invitable friends list

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using Facebook Javascript API for an App I'm developing in a secure canvas. I'm testing from within facebook with an app Admin account (therefore all permissions are granted).

In sync order I'm:

initializing the API -> logging in -> /me -> /me/invitable_friends.

The first 3 actions work as expected.
The last one - /me/invitable_friends - returns an empty data array.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: _“an app Admin account (therefore all permissions are granted)”_ – no, they are not. Your app can _ask_ for any permission, without having passed permission review by Facebook – but it still has to _ask_ the admin user for each permission it wants to use.

Comment: How do I make my app ask for that permission?

Comment: By specifying the permissions you want to ask for when calling the login dialog, in the way that the documentation says.

Comment: I did: `FB.login(onLogin, {scope: 'email,read_friendlists,user_location'});` and then confirmed when facebook asked me for permissions. Still returns an empty array.. When I check permissions with "/me/permissions" it returns "granted" for all permissions.

Comment: Well, as Gil said already, you need `user_friends` permission for invitable_friends. (`read_friendlists` will only give you the _names_ of any lists of friends the user has, and not even the friends that are in those lists.)

Comment: Solved, thank you. Would you like to write it in a proper answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Well, Gil kinda did already, so give him the points ;-) (If you were missing the bit about asking for permissions via the login dialog, ask him to add that to the answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"A common mistake when using the Invitable Friends API is not first verifying that your app has the required user_friends permission. It is necessary to have granted the user_friends permission in order to receive results from the Invitable Friends API. Without the permission, the response from Facebook will be an empty list."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2

Answer (score 3):

**April 4th, 2018 - Update**

Invitable Friends was deprecated on 4.4.18 and now return an empty list.
Facebook did it after Cambridge Analytica story.

Comment: Is there any other way to get list of friends to invite?

Comment: No, only way to use Facebook game request native dialog

Comment: Here is the official notice: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/