# Sending invitations to Facebook friends from iOS game without canvas presence

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, canvas, facebook

So I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412709/new-ios-app-struggling-with-facebook-graph-api-v2-0) that the invitable_friends API is only available for games that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation.

However, my situation is as follows: all I have is an iOS game, I created its FB account so that every user can log to Facebook and get the list of her/his Facebook friends playing my game in the game's social menu. So I'm interested if there exists some other way the user can get his Facebook friends not logged to my game in order to send them invitations to join my game?

Answer (score 1):

How to invite users in Apps without Canvas is explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

```
If your app does not have a presence on Facebook Canvas:
You may use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android, or the Send Dialog on Web.
```

So the recommended way in your case would be the Message Dialog.

Comment: Thank you, luschn for such a rapid answer. I've noticed that some iOS/Android games simply redirect from canvas to the game download site even though it is not FB recommended way, at least according to  some comments from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412709/new-ios-app-struggling-with-facebook-graph-api-v2-0).  Any other opinions related to that?

Comment: yes, that´s not allowed. you are not allowed to add canvas just for redirecting to your external app.

Comment: And please send me a message if you find apps doing that so I can forward them to Developer Operations to make sure that they follow our policies

Comment: in that case it´s a link to the facebook docs, should be no problem. but you may be right, i´ve added the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Two other options to invite Facebook friends are:

1. [Game Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#invites)
2. [App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios)

The advantage of #1 is that it returns you the Facebook IDs of the invited friends that you can then query in Facebook Graph and use in your pp immediately.

The advantage of #2 that you can provide deep links to the invitee to a specific place in your app.

Comment: for 1. game request : how can i send request to my friends who all have not installed my app. i mean how can i get the ID's of friends who all have not installed my app